# What the unit of this date calculation?

Tags: php, date

What is the unit in s or mn of this element?

```
$date = date('F d Y H:i:s.', filectime($filename))
$result = time() - $date;

$result  = 1492181252;
```

Is it in second?

Comment: to make sure that return in seconds value, `$result = time() - strtotime($date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP timestamps are seconds. It says it clearly in the documentation of [`time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).